# Printing out error messages in python

Tags: python

So for a point class I'm making I have this error class:

```
class Error(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
```

I'm using this to raise an error and print out a message for certain errors. What I'm doing here is printing out an error message if either x or y (or both) are not float values:

```
def __init__(self, x, y):
    if not isinstance(x, float):
        raise Error("Parameter \"x\" illegal.")
    self.x = x
    if not isinstance(y, float):
        raise Error ("Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
    self.y = y
```

By raising and printing errors that way, the error messages I get look like this:

```
********** Point
*** constructor
caught: Parameter "x" illegal.
caught: Parameter "y" illegal.
0
***
```

But the error message is actually supposed to look like this:

```
********** Point
*** constructor
caught: Parameter "x" illegal.
caught: Parameter "y" illegal.
0 1
***
```

So why does the expected output print a 1 next to the 0? Other error messages also include:

```
*** rotate
caught: Parameter "a" illegal.
0
***
```

When I want it to look like:

```
*** rotate
caught: Parameter "a" illegal.
0 -1
***
```

So is there something I'm not printing out in my error message? Here's the code that prints out the error message:

```
print '*** constructor'
try:
    p0 = Point(1,1.0) # x illegal
except Error as e:
    print 'caught:', e.message
try:
    p0 = Point(1.0,'y') # y illegal
except Error as e:
    print 'caught:', e.message

print Point(0.0,1.0)
```

Here's my *str* method:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(int(round(self.x)))
```

Comment: There's no printing in your code at all, not even the 0, so there is no way to help you. The problem is clearly in whatever code is doing the printing.

Comment: The code that does the printing is fine. I updated my code to show the actual code that prints out the message. I think the problem is at the end where it says print Point. It doesn't seem to be printing out the point.

Comment: You haven't shown us the definition of the `Point` class, specifically the `__str__` method, so we can't say for sure.  But here's my guess: Given your `__init__` method, `self.x` exists only if parameter `x` is a valid float, and likewise `self.y` exists only if parameters `x` and `y` are valid floats.  So, sometimes your `__str__` method only has one value to print.

Comment: Well, given that `__str__` method, it only returns __one__ value.  Why would you expect it to print two values?

Comment: I want the _str_ method to print two values. I used to have it as (self.x, self.y) but that doesn't work since if an error is raised then either x or y won't be interpreted as float values. So how can I get it to print 2 values.

Comment: If two valid float values aren't supplied, then `__init__` raises an exception and the Point object is not created, so you will never get as far as calling `__str__`, right?

Comment: Yes however it still needs to print out those two values.

Comment: So just define `__str__` to be: `return '%f %f' % (self.x, self.y)`.  If you're getting as far as calling `__str__`, then you can safely assume self.x and self.y exist.

Comment: It's almost right but the values it prints out has to be rounded ints. It cannot be doubles. If I put it as return '%f %f' % str(int(round(self.x, self.y))) then it returns an error.

Comment: You're passing both x and y to a single `round()` call.  Instead, call `int(round(..))` on each argument separately: `return '%d %d' % (int(round(self.x)), int(round(self.y)))`

Answer (score 0):

Default x and y to None:

```
x = None
y = None
```

Then in str method,

```
def __str__(self):
    str_x = ""
    if self.x is not None:
        str_x = str(int(round(self.x)))
    str_y = ""
    if self.y is not None:
        str_y = str(int(round(self.y)))
    return "%s %s" % (str_x, str_y)
```

Comment: The use of `raise` in the original `__init__` suggests that he does not want objects with invalid values to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use python's built-in raise?

It will terminate the program and show an error message, just like it came out of the interpreter.

If you're picky about the class, define it like this:

```
class YourNameHere(Exception): pass
```

Whether you defined the class or not, raise it like this:

```
raise ExampleError("Parameter \"x\" illegal.","Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
```

It will show the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/testanswer.py", line 3, in <module>
    raise ExampleError("Parameter \"x\" illegal.","Parameter \"y\" illegal.")
ExampleError: ('Parameter "x" illegal.', 'Parameter "y" illegal.')
```

For single answers, there is no need to put it in a tuple.